# How to use different textures in shader editor?

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

I know that my question is not understendable at all, but I don't know how to formulate it correctly, so I'll describe my situation. I download a model where there are 2 similar textures for body (nsfw, so I covered it):

1:
[image]

2:
[image]

So, as you can see the face is placed in different coordinates of uv, but when I'm trying to connect this textures directly in shader editor, I'm getting good result:

1:
[image]
2:
[image]

How could it work? When I'm exporting model to UE5 the 1 texture just doesn't work because of UV, so I thought the problem could be in UV layouts but no, there is only one main UV:
[image]
and the additional one for neck:
[image]
So the 1 texture just shouldn't work in Blender too, but it does. Why?

Comment: Hard to tell, you should go to File menu > External Data > Pack Resources, and upload the file.

Comment: @joshsanfelici well, I can't pack resources (this option is greyed out) and I can't upload the file because it's weight is 1.2GB

Comment: @vklidu why do you think I'm previewing the same texture? In 1 I'm using mercy_d texture, in 2 I'm using MercyShem_D texture, isn't it?

Comment: @vklidu sorry, I double checked it - I just don't have Viewer Node. I'm using node wrangler add-on, but when I'm clicking ctrl+shift+LMB, it's just connecting texture output to surface pin of material output node. I'm using blender 4.0.2.

Comment: @vklidu in 1 screenshot there is "Mercy_D.jpg" texture connected to material output. In 2 screenshot there is "MercyShem_D.png" texture connected to material output. It's different textures and I've posted it in the beginning of question, where the first one is called "Mercy_D.jpg" and second - "MercyShem_D.png". Another nodes are just color ramps, mix colors and other unrelated staff. I would like to share file, but after all cleanings where there is only head and materials left, it's weight is 756 Mb.

Comment: @vklidu There is only head and 1 material remain but size still 82Mb, so I can't upload it to blend-exchange. Here's google [drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15JWG-mIqcfP-lAjjV1nB_PncbIX4Wptt/view?usp=drive_link), if it's acceptable.

Comment: @vklidu done. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid "chatting" in comments I wrote summary here ...

For texture 1 and texture 2 you need individual *UV Map*, you can't achieve texturing with just a one *UVmap* for such textures.

... you are not getting "good result" in both screens (of viewport head), you are previewing the same [texture number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1viCZ.jpg) ([texture number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WHf4.png) is black haired lady). Why do you see the same texture is not clear from screens and since your shared file is different, so it is hard to say.

The file you shared in comment doesn't contain UV Map for texture 1.
So there is not a way to texture model with this texture (black haired lady). And this texture is not included in your blend either.

**For corrupted eyelashes UV** seen in [this UV map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8t2Q.jpg) just select edge and pres "V" to split vertices and in UV Editor select eyelashes by "L" (linked) and scale down and place somewhere (probably there is a part of texture to reserved for it).

[image]

### Edit

(related to comment) ... yes those are two things ... image choose in *Image Texture* node is similar to material in meaning - it is just a data container, that can store image data. Advantage of such system is that you can name it independently. The name of this texture container takes image name automatically when image is imported. Under node properties you can select as source data another image, but automatically taken name of the first image is kept ...

[image]

Comment: Ok, I just have one additional question which can make it clear for me: When I'm trying to select image in "Image Texture" node - I see texture name "Mercy_SSS.png", but when I'm unpacking this texture I'm getting texture named "Bayo_SSS.png". How could it be and could it be the reason of our misunderstanding?

Comment: See edit for more info ...

Comment: Well, I think it's best I can get with my current knowledge of Blender. Thank you for your  help and spended time.